# Singleton Safety with +(void)load

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

I've just been looking at the header files for NSObject, and I'm creating a singleton class. The problem I have is that it needs to load up basically from the start of the application, as the singleton maintains state for the application by observing NSNotifications and reporting the current state when asked.

My solution to this was to use the `+(void)load` method on NSObject. When the class loads into memory, I was going to override the load method, and allocate the singleton at that stage.

The documentation from Apple does not make it clear if it is safe to call `[[*class* alloc] init]` during the load method. I would generally assume it was, unless it was documented, but considering the importance of this item, and the fact that I'm loading this every time the app launches, I'd like to know anyone has any knowledge of whether this is safe or not, just for reassurance.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what exactly your class (and its superclasses) does when you call `init`. During `load`, other classes are not guaranteed to be available. If your class's `init` doesn't need any other classes, you might be able to get away with it.

It would be much safer to do this in `+ (void)initialize` instead, and if necessary to call a setup function during application launch (e.g. from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` on iOS).

Comment: Yes, this will do the trick. The key here is that +(void)initialize is called only once on program initialization for each class (!). For each class means that there is no need to call [super initialize]. On the other hand it is save to code +initialize in a way that it does not create any error or memory leaks when it is called twice just because the coder of a sub-class happens to call [super initialize] within the sub-class' +initialize method. Therefore you should be able to use it for the creation of the one and only singleton instance. On the other hand +init is probably better.

Comment: The problem that comes with +(void)initialize is documented in Apple's Docs: "The runtime sends initialize to each class in a program exactly one time just before the class, or any class that inherits from it, is sent its first message from within the program. (Thus the method may never be invoked if the class is not used.)" - I'm developing a static library where the users cannot know to call this method on loadup. The object must simply create its singleton on its own to monitor the state from the start, whether or not it is used. This is why I avoided +(void)initialize.